# Is this correct for the definition of a limit?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, definition

My teacher gave this as the definition of a limit:

> $$\lim_{x\to c} f(x) =L$$ if for each $\epsilon >0$, there is some $\delta >0$ such that $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ *as long as* $x \in (c-\delta, c+\delta ).$

Does the phrase "as long as" work here? In other texts I see $$\forall x, |x-c|< \delta \implies |f(x)-L|<\epsilon$$ and sometimes $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ *whenever* $x \in (c-\delta, c+\delta ).$ I guess my question is twofold: Is my teacher correct in saying "as long as" here? Also, did he need to say $x\in (c-\delta, c+\delta )$ *for each $x$*

Comment: It should be $x\in (c-\delta,c+\delta)\setminus\{c\}$ instead of $x\in (c-\delta,c+\delta)$.

Comment: I agree, is the definition proposed perhaps a sufficient replacement for the limit of $f$ being defined AND continuous as $c$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Whenever" is a clearer phrasing to use.  The intention of "as long as" is that $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$ for any value of $x$ satisfying $x \in (c-\delta, c+\delta)$, but it is not quite as clear.

As for the definition's use of the interval notation instead of $|x - c| < \delta$, that is inconsequential.  They are equivalent.

However, the more glaring omission is that the $\delta$-neighborhood $(c-\delta, c+\delta)$ needs to be *punctured*:  we must write $$x \in (c - \delta, c + \delta) \setminus c,$$ or $$0 < |x - c| < \delta.$$  You cannot include $x = c$ because $f$ is not necessarily defined at $c$.

Comment: Thank you. And this is actually something he said I was reading it incorrectly. At the end he wrote "but $x\neq c.$" Also, this definition *does* require that $(c-\delta,c)\cup(c, c+\delta)\subseteq \text{dom} f$ yes? That is, we must have $f$ be defined everywhere in $(c-\delta, c+\delta)$ other that at $x=c$ yes?